# How to invoke JS async method from Blazor

Tags: interop, filereader, blazor

I am trying to read some file using the `JSInterop` provided by `Blazor`.The problem is that even if in `.C#` i await the method ,  it seems it does not `await` it.Thus i can not retrieve the result provided by `js`.

**C#**

```
<input name="start" type="file" onchange="@(async(x)=>await OnChangeS(x))" />

@functions{
    private const string S = "start";

    public async Task OnChangeS(UIChangeEventArgs ev) {
        var str =  await JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync<string>("methods.readFile", S);
        Console.WriteLine("From blazor data is:" + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? "empty" : str));
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
  window.methods = {

    readFile: function (fileName) {

        let reader = new FileReader();
        var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file ][name=' + fileName + ']').files[0];
        var data = null;
        reader.onload = () => {
                data = reader.result;
                console.log("from load data is"+data);

        };
        reader.onloadend = () => {  console.log("from loadend data is"+data);return data };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**:
Given a sample `json` file :  `{ "name":"adita","age":33}` this is my output order:

```
WASM: Blazor S:empty

Fread.js:11 from load data is: {
    "name":"adita",
    "age":33
}
Fread.js:14 from loadend data is: {
    "name":"adita",
    "age":33
}
```

So my question is why is the method not awaited by `Blazor` ?

Comment: Your javascript function is not awaiting anything so in what sense is it actually async?

Comment: I just tried with `async` having no idea what else to try.It does not return anything with or without `async`.

Comment: Your javascript function is not returning anything at all -- what exactly are you expecting?

Comment: The events `onload` and `onloadend` are fired after the line `readAsText` so  if i return anything after that it won't return anything to `Blazor`.I thought that it would somehow pipe the return of `onloadend` to `Blazor`.

Comment: No, async/await in Javascript is pretty much the same as in C#.  It doesn't magically hook up to random events to return things.  You'll need to use the [deferred pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Deferred) in Javascript (analogous to `TaskCompletionSource` in C#)  (The link points out it's deprecated, but is more to the point, and you can figure out the modern syntax from the links there)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved it by wrapping my `FileReader` result in a `Promise`.I was not actually sending anything back as **@Kirk Woll** pointed out.

```
window.methods = {

    readFile: function (fileName) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {


            var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file ][name=' + fileName + ']').files[0];
            reader.onerror = () => { reader.abort(); reject("Error parsing file"); };
            reader.onload = () => {
                var data = reader.result;
                console.log("from load data is: " + data);
                resolve(data);


            };
            reader.readAsText(file);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but what if I need to return a value to Blazor ? I can't find a solution for such scenario (At least no easy one).

Comment: There's the reverse of the coin too using in Blazor a  static method with the `JSInvokeable` attribute around it. For more info check [here](https://blazor-university.com/javascript-interop/calling-dotnet-from-javascript/).

Comment: Thanks brother, this has helped me with my project.